# MySQL: No update statements working

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to update a table of my database with values from another table and database, using a common field.

However none of my statements are working and I can't figure out why. 
They are running for ten minutes (way too long) and then the server disconnects.

**First try:**

```
UPDATE database1.table1 t1, database2.table2 t2
SET t1.field1 = t2.field1
WHERE t1.field2 = t2.field2;
```

**Second try:**

```
UPDATE database1.table1 t1
INNER JOIN database2.table2 t2
ON t1.field2 = t2.field2
SET t1.field1 = t2.field1;
```

Can somebody push me in the right direction? 
The WHERE/ON-conditions are working in separate select statements. As a workaround I created new tables with a `SELECT` `JOIN`, but that is very slow work.

`field1` is unique in `table2`, but not `table1`. I want to update multiple entries in table1 with a unique value from `table2`.

Comment: field1 is unique in table2, but not table1. I want to update multiple entries in table1 with a unique value from table2.

Comment: Use this query to see what wrong iteration rows are you getting while running it : **SELECT t1.field2, t2.field2, t1.field1 AS ToBeAssignedToFourthColumn, t2.field1 AS ToBeChangedToThirdColumn FROM database1.table1 t1 INNER JOIN database2.table2 t2 ON t1.field2 = t2.field2**

Comment: Well to me this looks exactly as it should: 
http://666kb.com/i/d7v0ueu2l5z7abnz8.png

Autocommit off didn't change anything.